# Intercepting memory allocation calls on windows

Tags: windows, memory, system-calls, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

I was wondering it it's possible to "trap" memory allocation system calls (e.g. malloc) on windows. I want to be able to see the address, size and process the malloc call, if successful, returns. Basically I want to be able to listen in the the locations and processes that are requesting memory in real time.

Thanks